# Multiple response with render :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, controller

If I want to render 2 or more elements in my controller with `respond json:` what do I have to do? I tried:

```
render json: @user.errors.full_messages

//another element to render

render json: other element...
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `render json:` just one time.

One way to work around this is to build a single JSON that would contain both objects you want to return.

```
render json: {:errors => @user.errors.full_messages, 
              :other_element => other_element }
```